# When stacks don't help

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, stacks

Say I have a map between two coarse moduli spaces $f:M\to M'$, which is very clearly described (by performing some operation that works well for families). I want to prove that $f$ is formally unramified. Of course this can be checked on geometric fibers, so I can assume that everything is over some algebraically closed field $k$. If $\operatorname{char}k=0$, then I may do this by working on suitably defined stacks, finding the map between the completions of local rings thanks to deformation theory and then taking invariants. At least, this is a technique I am familiar with. But what can one do in positive characteristic? Are there in the literature some solved problems of this sort? It would be already enough to see how people work in these scenarios, maybe for related questions (not just unramifiedness).

Comment: It's not so much the stacks don't help, but the positive characteristic actively works against you...  :-)